# pySNMP Mib update from external thread

Tags: pysnmp

I'm implementing a PySNMP Agent process. Most of the examples are static agents serving default values in a single thread. Is it possible to update the MIB value of agent code from another thread? This thread should have master access to write all MIB values irrespective of VACM access.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried already?

Comment: Thanks. Used the sample code in the below link, <http://sirius.cs.put.poznan.pl/~inf94333/agentsnmp/agent.py>

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code to the post directly.

Comment: Any help please?  .... I need to update my snmp agent OIDs from another thread via. message queue dynamically ( Its different from SNMPSET - client perspective, since I need to update all OIDs irrespective of access - Agent perspective)

Comment: def thread_function():
      mibBuilder.exportSymbols( "MY-MIB2",  MibScalarInstance(opis.name, (3,), opis.syntax.clone("Nazw3"))) "

Comment: Hi @UwePlonus .. sorry I could not able to upload the code due to character limit. The above is the thread function which I used to "exportSymbols".Can you please help to understand pysnmp agent OID update?

Comment: Consider using articles in your writing. Also, there is not question as far as I can tell. It might help to add the code you are using into the question (you should be able to edit the question)